# Poisson equation, $L^2$ bounds

Tags: sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes, poissons-equation

Consider a bounded domain $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ and $u\in H^1_0(\Omega)$.

I know that
$$
\|u\|_{H^m}\leq C\|\Delta u\|_{H^{m-2}}
$$
for $m\geq 1$. Is the same true for $m=0$, i.e. for the $L^2$ norm of $u$?